# Dataguard broker reporting ORA-16801: redo transport-related property is inconsistent with database setting

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I have set up a dataguard config, and done most of the work from within DGMGRL to avoid possible issues, its seems to be running fine, but its reporting the following problem:

```
ORA-16801: redo transport-related property is inconsistent with database setting.
```

Looking at DGMGRL it gives me the following info:

```
DGMGRL> show database  'ELBEMP' 'InconsistentLogXptProps';
INCONSISTENT LOG TRANSPORT PROPERTIES
   INSTANCE_NAME         STANDBY_NAME        PROPERTY_NAME         MEMORY_VALUE         BROKER_VALUE

          ELBEMP              ELBEMS1           LogXptMode       (missing SRLs)                ASYNC

          ELBEMP              ELBEMS2           LogXptMode       (missing SRLs)                ASYNC

          ELBEMP              ELBEMS3           LogXptMode       (missing SRLs)                ASYNC
```

I have added SRL to the primary, and they have been copied over to the standby when I created it via rman

Logs on the primary:

```
1 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo01.rdo
1 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo01.rdo
2 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo02.rdo
2 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo02.rdo
3 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo03.rdo
3 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo03.rdo
4 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby04a.log
4 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby04b.log
5 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby05a.log
5 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby05b.log
6 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby06a.log
6 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby06b.log
7 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby07a.log
7 - STANDBY - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrarch/redostby07b.log
```

These are the logs on one of the standbys (ELBEMS3):

```
SQL> select group# ||' - '|| type ||' - '|| member from v$logfile;

GROUP#||'-'||TYPE||'-'||MEMBER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo01.rdo
1 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo01.rdo
2 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo02.rdo
2 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo02.rdo
3 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/origlog/redo03.rdo
3 - ONLINE - /oracle/ELBEMP/mirrlog/redo03.rdo
```

I will be honest I was expecting the logs to be ELBEMS3 and not ELBEMP, but everything seems to be applying and there are no non applied logs in v$archived_log

Anyone have any ideas of how to get rid of the error message?

Comment: Question might be more appropriate for serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you don't actually have any standby redo logs defined in the standby database - all your logfiles are ONLINE. You will need to create the standby logfiles on the standby databases as well. See the [Data Guard Concepts and Administration Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/create_ps.htm#i1225703).

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could drop the standby logs from the primary. Strictly speaking you don't have to operate with standby redo logs - they're only required for Real-Time Apply and maximum protection and maximum availability levels of data protection in Data Guard. Oracle does recommend using standby redo logs, and there's really no reason not to (and [several reasons why you should](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14239/standby.htm#i72373)). You really aren't using them at the moment anyway - the ones defined on the primary are only used if you switchover and make the primary a standby.

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion I was coming to, I think I do need the systems in maximum protection so I will disable the dataguard confuration and add the standby logs to the primarys.

Am I right to assume that because I didnt have SRLs on the standbys it was not doing Async dataguarding but resorting to applying the logs instead?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, one more thing, I have tried the following to disable the config

On the primary instance

SQL> alter database add standby logfile group 6('/oracle/ELBEMS1/mirrarch/redostby06a.log','/oracle/ELBEMS1/mirrarch/redostby06b.log') size 100M
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01156: recovery in progress may need access to files


Any ideas, on how I can allow me to add these standby logs while database is in physical standby mode?

Comment: Sorry there are some problems with the above comment.

On primary I disabled using DGMGRL 
Conect internal
disable configuration;

And then did the above on the standby, and received that message.

Comment: Solved the problem. For anyone Interested, its this.  I ran the following to fix the issue:

on primary
dgmgrl
connect /
disable configuration;

got to each standby and run :

alter database recover managed standby database cancel;

---- Create 1 more additional group then you have redo log groups on primary (so primary had 3, I am going to create 4.

alter database add standby logfile group <n> (<filename>) size <size>; 

alter database recover managed standby database disconnect; 

Back on primary
dgmgrl
connect /
enable configuration;

Comment: You are correct - ASYNC log transfer mode requires standby logfiles. If you are using Grid Control, there are some pretty nice Data Guard tools in there, and it gives you immediate feedback that you can't do ASYNC without them.